# Trigger to allow only 1 car

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to make a trigger which will set a constraint that a person can only rent one car.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Carperperson
BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.vehicle_id = ?THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text='You can only book one car per single customer a day!';


DELIMITER;
```

That's where I got so far and if to be honest I'm kind of stuck how to structure this.

Tables:

```
Bookings, Customers, Vehicles, 
Chauffeurs, Vehicle_Collections, 
Payments, Mechanics, Invoice
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as general advice, this seems like it should be part of the business layer (eg: part of the procedure that inserts new reservations) rather than a trigger. This is because triggers can have a pretty hefty performance impact, and the procedure will need to look out for custom error messages and surface those to the end user.

As for the logic, car rentals can be for a range of days, so you basically have two scenarios, the customer already has a rental that is not returned before the start of the rental to be inserted, or is planning on starting a new rental before the rental being inserted is scheduled to be returned. An allowable case that might conflict with those is if the user is dropping off a car in one location and picking up a car in another location on the same day, so we have to take that into consideration.

Without knowing your table structure, it's a little hard to give exact T-SQL code on how to handle those. I'm going to assume for demonstrative purposes that you have a table with UserID, CarID, pickupdate and dropoffdate, and that new rows are inserted with all four of those values.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Carperperson
BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.User_ID = bookings.User_ID
    and ((new.Pickupdate >= bookings.pickupdate and new.Pickupdate < bookings.dropoffdate)
        or (new.dropoffdate > bookings.pickupdate and new.dropoffdate < bookings.dropoffdate))
THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text='You can only book one car per single customer a day!';


DELIMITER;
```

I hope this shows how in general it should work, even if it doesn't exactly map to your data structure. I'd warn you again that this is a really bad idea as a trigger.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for a quick reply. What would you suggest instead of a trigger? Just to clarify, im not looking for the actual answer